# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./gspca_kinect2.ko: Unknown symbol in module

Tags: drivers, kernel, uefi, c++, 21.10

I tried to compile and run the driver "gspca-kinect2" because I want that my kinect 2 is detected as webcam inside obs and skype,but as u can see below,it does not work :

```
marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ uname -a

Linux marietto-BHYVE 5.13.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:47 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania$ git clone https://github.com/grandchild/gspca-kinect2.git

Clone in 'gspca-kinect2' in corso...
remote: Enumerating objects: 95, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 95 (delta 6), reused 8 (delta 3), pack-reused 81
Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (95/95), 69.96 KiB | 884.00 KiB/s, fatto.
Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (52/52), fatto.

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania$ cd gspca-kinect2

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ ls

gspca.c  gspca.h  kinect2.c  kinect2.h  LICENSE  Makefile  README.md

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` SRCROOT=`pwd` clean modules
make: ingresso nella directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/kinect2.o
  LD [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_kinect2.o
  CC [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca.o
  LD [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_main.o
  MODPOST /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_kinect2.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_kinect2.ko
  BTF [M] /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_kinect2.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_kinect2.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
  CC [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_main.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_main.ko
  BTF [M] /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_main.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /home/marietto/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2/gspca_main.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make: uscita dalla directory «/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic»

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ sudo /sbin/modprobe videodev

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ sudo /sbin/insmod ./gspca_main.ko
```

---

```
marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ modinfo gspca_main.ko | grep depends

depends:        videobuf2-v4l2,videodev,videobuf2-vmalloc,videobuf2-common
marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ sudo make install
[sudo] password di marietto: 
make: ***  no rule to make target «install». stop.

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ sudo depmod -a

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ sudo modprobe gspca_main

marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ ffmpeg  -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0  test.avi

ffmpeg version 4.4-6ubuntu5 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=6ubuntu5 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x562bc5c93400] Cannot open video device /dev/video0: No such file or directory
/dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the module have dependencies that need to be loaded first? `modinfo gspca_main.ko | grep depends` Is there any reason you didn't proceed to `sudo make install` and then `sudo depmod -a` so that you can simply: `sudo modprobe gspca_main` ?

Comment: marietto@marietto-BHYVE:~/Scrivania/gspca-kinect2$ modinfo gspca_main.ko | grep depends
depends:        videobuf2-v4l2,videodev,videobuf2-vmalloc,videobuf2-common

Comment: I have only followed the instructions on the github page,here : https://github.com/yoshimoto/gspca-kinect2

Comment: I suggest that you wait for the code author to respond to your issue: https://github.com/yoshimoto/gspca-kinect2/issues/18

Comment: I know man,but It could never happen that he will reply. I don't have so much time to spend. Based on my experience a github author could never reply. So I will continue asking on the various forums all around the net.

Comment: do u know if that's the only driver that is available for making work the kinect 2 as a webcam ? maybe If there is another one,I can jump there and in this case,I can wait.

Comment: I do not. I suggest that you try the steps I recommended above and then see if it modprobes. It is easy to reverse.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7jcPQhx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133381/discussion-between-chili555-and-marietto).